# empty($_POST) === FALSE doesn't work as it should

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, is-empty

I was testing the empty function in php, but it doesn't work, because the if statement is accessible  whether the condition is false or true.

```
<?php
    if(empty($_POST) === false){

        echo 'text';
}
?>



<form action="index.php"  method="post">
    Username:
    <input type="text" name="text">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The echo  is executed even if the input is empty.

Why ??

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump($_POST)` before this `if` statement?  `$_POST` is probably not empty when you expect it to be.

Comment: Even if the inputs themselves are empty, the empty values are still posted. Your `if` would work only if there were no inputs at all underneath the form.

Comment: Thank you all I will to use  var_dump($_POST)  because I have never seen it before!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `$_POST` will NEVER be empty after receiving a POST request from a `form` with `input` values inside it.

If you `var_dump` yours, you'll see:

```
textarray(2) { ["text"]=> string(0) "" ["submit"]=> string(12) "Submit Query" }
```

Even your `submit input` is sent (as it is part of the `form`). And even without receiving anything, `$_POST` will return an empty set array, so neither `isset` is a good option to check POST fail or success.

You need to evaluate a specific field, like `$_POST['text']`, for emptiness instead.

Comment: Thank you very much,  I used it as the tutorials I watching. That why I was confused. Thank you.

Comment: @AhmadzIssa Consider accepting his answer by clicking on the tick button below the vote count of this answer, if it helped you resolve your problem. cheers x)

Comment: I had to wait 5 mints  to do that ^^.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset $_POST["text"] && $_POST["text"] !=null)
```

also, try using == instead of === 
== will cast the value of $_POST, so if it's NULL, it will be evaluated as false instead

Comment: What is `!-=`? I never saw it before

Comment: `!-=null`? might want to look at that a bit more closely. And no, don't use `==`. That'll make `0` test as equal as well, and the empty string... both of which are perfectly valid form submission values.

Comment: Fixed the Typo, sorry guys.
I suggested == because he's evaluating $_POST, not a post variable